# Conflicting theorems regarding eigenvalues & matrix diagonalisability

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have the two following theorems:

- Matrix $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if the algebraic multiplicity equals the geometric multiplicity for every eigenvalue and all its eigenvalues are inside its field.
- If matrix $A$ has a single eigenvalue it is diagonalisable if and only if it is a scalar matrix.

I have the following matrix above $\mathbb{R}$:

[image]

I calculated its characteristic polynomial to be $\lambda^3 - 8$, which in turn means $\lambda = 2$ is its only eigenvalue, which leads to a conflict between the theorems — the first theorem says it's diagonalisable, second does not.

Why?

Comment: Does "singular eigenvalue" mean it is non-invertible? Is $2$ non-invertible? What field are you working on?

Comment: @Leo Sorry, forgot to mention that it's above the real field.

Comment: "singular eigenvalue " means a single eigenvalue ?

Comment: @leonbloy It means that there could not be two or more different eigenvalues.

Comment: @daedsidog "Single" is a better word to use. "Singular" has other meanings in the context of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both theorems imply your example is not diagonalizable. There are complex roots of $\lambda^3-8=0$, so not all eigenvalues are in the real field.

Comment: @Bungo Oh, I'm really not thinking straight today.

Comment: @Bungo Edited, thanks for the correction!