# Question regarding a theorem about the number of eigenvalues in a matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having a problem with this theorem:
Matrix $A_{n\times n}$ has no more than $n$ different eigenvalues.

Now I have the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&2&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 4&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and the elements are from $\mathbb{Z}_7$.
I found its characteristic polynomial to be $\lambda^3 - 8$ which is $\lambda^3 + 6$ above $\mathbb{Z}_7$, now using the polynomial, I found the eigenvalues are $1,2,4$ because $1^3 = 1$, $2^3 = 8 = 1$, $4^3 = 64 = 1$ above $\mathbb{Z}_7$ which means I have 3 different eigenvalues.
But my problem is that from $\lambda^3 - 1$ , I also get the eigenvalues $1\operatorname{cis}(0)$, $1\operatorname{cis}(120)$ and $1\operatorname{cis}(240)$, for a total of 6 eigenvalues.
Are those not eigenvalues because I'm not in the complex number field?, if yes that conflicts the question asked in the following link: [Conflicting theorems regarding eigenvalues & matrix diagonalisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324425/conflicting-theorems-regarding-eigenvalues-matrix-diagonalisibility), (the matrix is above $\mathbb{R}$, but has complex eigenvalues).

Comment: You can't switch fields in the middle of a computation!

Comment: I found the polynomial by calculating the determinant of $\lambda*I - A$, when I transfer it to $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and then calculate I still get $\lambda^3 + 6$, can you explain which part?

Comment: If your matrices are over $\mathbb{Z}_7,$ then use that field, and only that field, to find your eigenvalues. There's no way you could get $1, e^{2i\pi/3},$ and $e^{4i\pi/3}$ if you're working in $\mathbb{Z}_7.$ Conversely, while you would get $1$ if you're working in $\mathbb{C},$ you wouldn't get the other integers as eigenvalues. The context of the problem should tell you which field to use.

Comment: I understand, that's what I thought too, but in the attached link the elements are above the real numbers and the answer indicates that the matrix has eigenvalues above the complex numbers and that is why it's not diagonalizable.

Comment: @LiorB that works because the complex numbers are the complex extension of $\Bbb R$.  They are not, however, the complex extension of $\Bbb Z_7$

Comment: If you wanted to take an analogous approach here, you would have to use the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: but eigenvalues are scalars from the field, if my field is $\mathbb{R}$ how can the scalars be complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Your field of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ does not contain complex numbers.

In  $\mathbb{Z}_7$  the class of   $-1$ does not have a square root because there is no square congruent to $6$ mod (7).

That is your field does not have a complex extension.

Comment: In the attached link, the matrix is above $\mathbb{R}$ but the answer to that question indicates that the matrix has eigenvalues above the complex numbers hence why it is not a diagonalizable matrix.